# Unable to send email in remote server

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, jakarta-mail, remote-server

I have a java code which is used to send an email via smtp protocol on port 587. I am using javax mail api for this. I am able to send mail on localhost (both windows and ubuntu) machines.

The problem arises when I had created a war file and deployed on a remote server having ubuntu OS moreover, there is no error in logs. Please help what could be the probable reason and how to solve it.

Here is my sample spring-java code

```
public void sendMailForResetPassword(String emailId ) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
     EmailDataObject emailproperties=new EmailDataObject();

     try {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", emailproperties.host_name);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
      props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust",  emailproperties.host_name);
      props.put("mail.smtp.UseDefaultCredentials",  false);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication( emailproperties.from, emailproperties.password);
        }
      });




    String link = "www.example.com";
              System.out.println("This is best way for forgot password");
      StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder(); 


    bodyText.append("<div>")
             .append("  Dear User<br/><br/>")
             .append("  We got your reset password request, Find below link to reset password <br/>")
             .append("  Please click <a href=\""+link+"\">here</a> or open below link in browser<br/>")
             .append("  <br/><br/>")

             .append("</div>");
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailproperties.from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(emailId));
        message.setSubject("Reset Password");
        message.setContent(bodyText.toString(), "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        session.setDebug(true);

        System.out.println(message);
        Transport.send(message);



     }  catch (MessagingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

**Edit**

This is the output of the session.setDebug(true);

```
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ETRN", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
 STARTTLS 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
 EHLO ubuntu-minimal
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you  show us the error/Exception

Comment: Is it the exact code you have in the server? If so emailproperties is just initialized and how are you getting the values for username and password for "PasswordAuthentication". And where are your loggers which indicates session established or not.

Comment: The username and password is defined in the EmailDataObject class. I cannot disclose it's information due to security reasons, however I assure you that I'm getting valid userid and password.

Comment: This is the output of   session.setDebug(true); DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ETRN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO ubuntu-minimal

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're getting stuck at the point where the client announces its name to the server.  Perhaps the server doesn't like the fact that you haven't used a valid DNS name?  If the name service on the client machine is properly configured, JavaMail (via the JDK) should be able to determine the DNS name of the client machine.  Since that's not working, you can override it by setting the JavaMail SMTP Session property [`mail.smtp.localhost`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.localhost) to a valid fully qualified DNS host name for your client machine.

Note also that you can simplify your code by [getting rid of the Authenticator](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the `Transport` about the `Session` as well as connect them and close the `Transport` afterwards, try

```
    Transport smtpTransport = session.getTransport();
    smtpTransport.connect();
    smtpTransport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    smtpTransport.close();
```

instead of just

```
    Transport.send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had found answer of above question using Email class in java.

```
final Email email = new Email();

String host = hostname;
Integer port = portNumber;
String from = emailFrom;
String pass = emailFromPassword;
String[] to = emailTo;

String msgBody = "Hello";
email.setFromAddress("", from);
email.setSubject("Demo");
for( int i=0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
    email.addRecipient("", to[i], RecipientType.TO);
}
email.setTextHTML(msgBody);

new Mailer(host, port, from, pass).sendMail(email);
```